# Jquery mobile and IOS address bar

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I am having some issues with ios devices due to the URL Address bar. I am using Esri Javascript api maps and Jquery mobile. When i change page, i re-size my map but due to the URL bar on top not being fixed i get white spaces at the bottom because it not able to get the Exact height. 
Can Anyone tell me how to address this problem. 
I tried using scroll top but does not help. I am been struggling with this for almost a day. Is there any way i could always show the address bar or hide the address bar for few pages only.

Thanks, 
Pawan

Answer (score 0):

You can update the height of your container element in a `window.resize` event handler:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    $('#container').height($(this).height());
});
```

This is of-course very simplified, you'll most likely have to do a bit of math to figure-out the exact height of the container.

I would also add a timeout so this only fires once per resize (different browsers send different numbers of resize events as the browser resizes):

```
var timer;
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#container').height($(this).height());
    }, 50);
});
```

As the address bar is hidden, `resize` events are fired since the view-port is changing sizes.

Comment: thanks for the help. I am doing a resize and it does resize. but since the map is loaded when the application is first loaded but not the active view, and when it becomes active it does not show the address bar and scrolls to the header directly. page calculates the width right just that it scrolls to the header.when i scroll up i see the header. In Android it works fine. Only IOS is having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is an orientation change event for JQM,

```
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
    /* your codes here */
});
```